# Android and Jenkings build, using Gradle

Tags: android, jenkins, gradle

I'm having an annoying problem trying to integrate **Android gradle** with **Jenkins Android Emulator Plugin**.
I set those properties to my Android Emulator:

- Android OS version: android-18
- Screen density: 160
- Screen resolution: HVGA
- Device locale: es_ES
- Target ABI: armeabi-v7a
- Emulator name suffix: android18

When I start the process, the emulator starts propertly, but I get the following error:

```
[Gradle] - Launching build.
[workspace] $ /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/properati-android/workspace/gradlew clean assemble
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugCompile'.
   > Could not find com.android.support:support-v4:20.0.0.
     Required by:
         workspace:app:unspecified
```

In Gradle plugin settings  (on Jenkins as a command line Task) I'm using **gradlew clean assemble** command to build

The following are the **build.gradle** files I'm currently using in my project.

1)  Main gradle file

```
projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.2'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

configurations {
    all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
}
```

2) Project Gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 20
    buildToolsVersion '20.0.0'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.app"
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 20
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.0.0'
    compile 'com.googlecode.android-query:android-query:0.25.9'
    compile 'com.github.castorflex.smoothprogressbar:library:0.5.2'
}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.newrelic.agent.android:agent-gradle-plugin:3.+'
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

    apply plugin: 'android'
    apply plugin: 'newrelic'

dependencies {
    compile 'com.newrelic.agent.android:android-agent:3.+'
}
```

I would appreciate any help or tip you could share. Thanks in advance!

***UPDATE & Solution***:

I solved this issue by adding AndroidSupportV4.jar to my libs folder and changing my build.gradle file to the following:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    //compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:20.0.0' --OLD LINE
    compile files ("libs/AndroidSupportV4.jar")        --NEW LINE
    compile 'com.googlecode.android-query:android-query:0.25.9'
    compile 'com.github.castorflex.smoothprogressbar:library:0.5.2'
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't You install Android Support Library and Android Support Repository from Extras in Android SDK Manager?

Comment: I'm currently using a machine without a UI. Using list sdk command from command line I can install the following packages: (see edit)

Comment: Also have a look here: https://github.com/makinacorpus/android-archetypes/wiki/Getting-started%3A-Building-Android-apps-with-Jenkins-CI

Comment: That link reffers to a Maven tutorial, I'm currently using Gradle.

Comment: Can you try "android list sdk --all" on jenkins server? also please look at configurations {
    all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
} I think this is not correct

Comment: @RodrigoTrindade, yes, this is maven tutorial, but rather have a look at `android` commands, please.